# Overcoming max persistent connections by using both root domain and www?

Tags: http, persistent-connection

I've read about overcoming the max persistent connections of a browser by [using various subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) and also by [using various ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283776/overcoming-max-persistent-connections-with-different-ports).

Do browsers treat example.com and www.example.com as different hosts? This would obviously be the quick win for many who developer websites with a large number of images, css files and javascript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are different hosts and browsers treat them as such. It is just the common practice that usually one redirects to another but that is only a practice, not the rule.

Comment: and you could redirect only for page requests which are found, but need the www adding or removing.